# A fair coin is tossed three times

Tags: probability

A fair coin is tossed three times.

A: Event that a head occurs on each of the first two tosses.

B: Event that a tail occurs on the third toss.

C: Event that exactly two tails occur in the three tosses.

a) Show that A and B are independent.

b) Show that B and C are dependent.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you know the definition of independence between two events?

Comment: Yes, I found P(A), P(B) and P(C). I know that A and B are independent, B and C dependent but I don't know how to show and prove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To begin, lets find all of the possibilities for coin flips, this will be useful later. This will just be all possible binary strings of length 3. So we will have $TTT$, $TTH$, $THT$, $THH$, $HTT$, $HTH$, $HHT$, and $HHH$, with 8 total possibilites.

To show A and B are independent, it is sufficient to show that $P(A\cap B)=P(A)\cdot P(B)$. To begin, the cases that satisfy $A\cap B$ are just $HHT$, so $P(A\cap B)=\frac{1}{8}$. Next, the cases that satisfy $A$ are just $HHT$ and $HHH$, so $P(A)=\frac{2}{8}=\frac{1}{4}$. Then, the cases that satisfy $B$ are $TTT$, $THT$, $HTT$, and $HHT$, so $P(B)=\frac{4}{8}=\frac{1}{2}$. Putting this all together, we find that $P(A)\cdot P(B)=\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{8}=P(A\cap B)$, so that A and B are independent.

To show that B and C are dependent, it is sufficient to show that $P(B\cap C) \ne P(B)\cdot P(C)$ The results that satisfy B and C are $THT$, and $HTT$, so $P(B\cap C)=\frac{2}{8}=\frac{1}{4}$. The results that satisfy B are $TTT$, $THT$, $HTT$, and $HHT$, so $P(B)=\frac{4}{8}=\frac{1}{2}$. The results that satisfy C are $TTH$, $THT$, and $HTT$. Thus $P(C)=\frac{3}{8}$. Thus, $P(B)\cdot P(C)=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{3}{8}=\frac{3}{16}\ne\frac{1}{4}=P(B\cap C)$. Thus, $P(B)\cdot P(C)\ne P(B\cap C)$, so that B and C are dependent.

Answer (score -1):

Two events $A$ and $B$ are independent when $P(A\cap B) = P(A)P(B)$.

$P(A) = \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 = \frac{1}{4}$ because each toss is independent and there is a 50% chance for heads on each of the first two tosses.

$P(B) = \frac{1}{2}$ because there is a 50% chance of landing tails.

$P(C) = \binom{3}{2}\frac{1}{2^3} = \frac{3}{8}$ because we need to choose 2 of the 3 tosses to be tails (the remaining one is heads) and each toss has a 50% chance of landing on the desired outcome.

Then $A\cap B$ is having tosses $HHT$ which has a $\frac{1}{8}$ probability. So $P(A\cap B) = \frac{1}{8} = P(A)P(B)$ so they are independent.

And $B\cap C$ is having two tails and one head when the last flip is tails. So the possible tosses are $HTT$ and $THT$. So $P(B\cap C) = \frac{1}{4}$, but $P(B)P(C) = \frac{3}{16}$.